# Undo documentation proposal commit

Tags: support, tags, documentation-proposals

I have committed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/crm/commit) documentation proposal but now I realize that I shouln't.

`crm` tag y quite open and its definition is quite generic so I don't think a valuable documentation could be added to this tag.

Why is not possible to undo the commits on a tag?